# pandas compare certain colum entries by date and value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

my problem:

```
 df1 = [{'Day': '2019-12-01', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-01', 'Price': '50'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-02', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-01', 'Price': '45'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-03', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-01', 'Price': '40'},
       {'Day': '2019-12-02', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-02', 'Price': '50'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-03', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-02', 'Price': '42'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-04', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-02', 'Price': '41'}, 
      {'Day': '2019-12-03', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-03', 'Price': '60'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-04', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-03', 'Price': '50'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-05', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-03', 'Price': '48'} 

]
```

Now I'd like to automatically compare the Price of the Issue date, with the price for the same date the day before.

To find out, how much the price rose from yesterday to today and create a new column with this value.

For Example: I'd like to compare the price of the 02nd of December in 'Issue Date: 2019-12-02 (Price = 45),
to the Price of the 2nd of December in 'Issue Date: 2019-12-01' (Price = 50). The Result should be Plus 10 %.

And so on.
How do I do that?

Comment: Question.   There are more that one Issue Date in the Day field, which to use?  IE... 2019-02-02 is the Issue Date, but there are more than one 2019-02-02 in Date column, which price to use?

Comment: The Price of the day before, The Issue Date minus one and then this price would do.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I understand your problem correctly, try this:

```
df1 = [{'Day': '2019-12-01', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-01', 'Price': '50'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-02', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-01', 'Price': '45'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-03', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-01', 'Price': '40'},
       {'Day': '2019-12-02', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-02', 'Price': '50'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-03', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-02', 'Price': '42'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-04', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-02', 'Price': '41'}, 
      {'Day': '2019-12-03', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-03', 'Price': '60'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-04', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-03', 'Price': '50'},
 {'Day': '2019-12-05', 'Issue Date': '2019-12-03', 'Price': '48'} 

]

df = pd.DataFrame(df1)

df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(int)

df['Issue Price'] = df.loc[df['Day'] == df['Issue Date'], 'Price']

df['Issue Price'] = df['Issue Price'].ffill()

df['Pct Change'] = (df['Issue Price'] - df['Price']) / df['Issue Price']
df
```

Output:

```
          Day  Issue Date  Price  Issue Price  Pct Change
0  2019-12-01  2019-12-01     50         50.0    0.000000
1  2019-12-02  2019-12-01     45         50.0    0.100000
2  2019-12-03  2019-12-01     40         50.0    0.200000
3  2019-12-02  2019-12-02     50         50.0    0.000000
4  2019-12-03  2019-12-02     42         50.0    0.160000
5  2019-12-04  2019-12-02     41         50.0    0.180000
6  2019-12-03  2019-12-03     60         60.0    0.000000
7  2019-12-04  2019-12-03     50         60.0    0.166667
8  2019-12-05  2019-12-03     48         60.0    0.200000
```